# RSpec fails because actual redirect has a flash message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, rspec

ThingsController:

...

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to(:action => "new", :notice => "its a good thing!")}  # suspect...
end
```

When I test this code

```
  it "should redirect to /employees/new with a success notice" do
    post :create, :employee => Factory.build(:employee).attributes
    response.should redirect_to(:action => "new")
    flash[:notice].should_not be_nil
  end
```

The test fails because it does NOT expect the actual redirection to have a notice.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code works perfectly fine for me on Rails 3 with Rspec 2.5. Can you post your full "should redirect to new with notice" spec, not just the `response.should` line?

Comment: If I change     response.should redirect_to(:action => "new", "notice => "its a good thing!")  
This passes, but I don't actually want to test the exact message, just that its present.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, I have suggestion: test different things on different lines.

```
response.should redirect_to(new_thing_path)
flash[:notice].should eql("its a good thing!")
```

This way, if the `redirect_to` fails it will fail on that line, and if the `flash[:notice]` is broken it will fail on that line.

Additionally, your test should work.

Comment: when I do   response.should redirect_to(new_thing_path)  it gives me an error saying it expected to be redirected to /things/new  but was redirected to /things/new?notice=its a good thing

Comment: @recursive_acronym: Please show us your exact code, I think you may not be using @thing.

Comment: I changed redirect_to(:action => "new", :notice => "...")   to redirect_to(new_thing_path, :notice=>"...")  and now it specs properly. It still seems a bit odd but at least its moving forward now.   Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I know you already have an answer accepted, but I wanted to provide more insight on the issue here.  The real reason your original code was failing is because this:

```
redirect_to(:action => "new", :notice => "its a good thing!")
```

Is essentially the same as this:

```
url = url_for(:action => "new", :notice => "its a good thing!")
redirect_to(url)
```

In the above, it's easier to see that the value of `url` will assume that `:notice` is a parameter you're trying to pass as part of the URL.  What you're trying to do is pass `:notice` as an option to `redirect_to`, but it's being merged with your other hash options to form a URL.

Here are two (untested) solutions to try:

```
redirect_to({:action => "new"}, {:notice => "its a good thing!"})
```

or:

```
redirect_to(url_for(:action => "new"), :notice => "its a good thing!")
```